# Issue with custom exim filter

Tags: email, filter, syntax, exim

I am attempting to create some rules to help deal with the outbound spam we've seen lately from our customers being compromised. To do this I'm using an Exim filter and I need to discard the emails which includes numbers from 0-9 for example:

```
  $sender_address: contains "@domain.com"
  $header_subject: contains "^([0-9]+)\@domain\.com"
```

However, the filter is not working as expected. I want to discard the emails which are received from domain.com like 123@domain.com | 234567@domain.com

I tried many tricks, but none of them was working.

Answer (score 0):

For the regex matching, try using `matches` instead of `contains`

`$header_subject: matches "^([0-9]+)\@domain\.com"`